# Positioning the export statement in ES2015 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Regarding the usage of the export statement, I would like to know if there is any particular benefits/disadvantages of using each of the following approaches:

Together with the declaration:

```
function f0(){}

export function f1(){}

export function f2(){}
```

Or at the end of the module:

```
function f0(){}

function f1(){}

function f2(){}

//...

export {
    f1,
    f2
}
```

The way I see it, the first approach has the clear advantage of letting me know imediatly what is private to the module, specially when looking at a big file.
On the other hand, the second approach shows in a single place all the public stuff.

Comment: Choose whatever you like best.

Comment: i agree with @FelixKling. i personally prefer the second approach since you can easily see the module's API in one spot.